# Understanding model, texture, UV scale

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I am trying to understand the relationship between the scale of the model and how a texture is applied. My workflow is as follows:

1. Create a model
2. Create an image in the UV/Image editor of the default size, 1024x1024
3. UV Unwrap (for my current project just using a smart UV project)
4. Export UV map to create textures
5. Export model to .fbx
6. Combine model & texture in Unity3d

After I'm in Unity, I usually end up scaling my model, and my texture looks quite pixelated, and I'm not sure how to correct that. Theoretically I would ideally not change scale in Unity, but then I'm not sure how the other steps are related. Should I scale up the model first, and THEN do my UV unwrap? Scale the unwrapped UV image? I've got pretty large textures that have to be cut down quite a bit to even fit in the 1024x1024 UV map that is exported. Another thought I had was to start with like a 4096x4096 image.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about unity, but at least in blender UV maps are not defined in pixels. The UV map defines a mapping for the 2D image on the 3D surface of the model. The 2D image can be any resolution you want, the only limitation is performance.

Comment: @gandalf3 this sounds like "start with a bigger image exporting UVs"? It seems like scaling the UV map after the fact would screw up the coordinate mapping.

Comment: You shouldn't need (or want) to scale the UV map.. Simply using a higher resolution image should work. (The size of the UV map and the resolution of the image are not really related)